# I am having a hard time defining and displaying the average of an array of strings inputted by the user and displaying all number above 3.4

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, integer

The code is ideal for grades or GPA's, I am trying to display the average `(GPAtotal / gpa.length)` of the grades that is input by the user into an array. I was also asked to display a list of the outstanding GPA’s (Defined as GPA’s over `3.4`)

I've tried:

- Using `parseInt()` converting the input from string in an array to integers in an array.
- Using `gpa.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / gpa.length`, but the input are still string.

I've type of conversions to convert the strings into integers.

```
var gpa = [];
var theGPA = "";
while (theGPA != "XXX")
{
    theGPA = prompt("Enter GPA or XXX to Stop");

    if (theGPA != "XXX") {
        gpa.push(theGPA);
    }
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "Average: " + "???" + "<br/>";
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += "Outstanding GPA: " + "???";
```

When attempting to display the average I would get the user imputed string as one solution, Example:

```
array: ["3.4", "4.0", "2.6"]
outputting: "Average: 4.04.32.6"
```

Comment: You can use `gpa.push(+theGPA);` to convert the string to number when pushing into the array. Read about [unary plus here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()). After that, `gpa.reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) / gpa.length` should give what you expect.

Comment: Hint: `map` using `parseInt`, then `reduce` the result of that map. Break down big problems into smaller ones. `gpa.map(...).reduce(...)` as a template. You could also push a value already processed with `parseInt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code utilizing some of suggestions above

```js
const gpa = ["3.4", "4.0", "2.6"];

const total = gpa.map(gpa => +gpa) // Map string to numeric (note the +)
    .reduce((avg, gpa) => avg += gpa); // Sum the gpa's
const average = total / gpa.length; // Compute average
console.log(`Average: ${average.toFixed(2)}`); // toFixed converts to a string, don't use it if you want to do math with the result!
```